# Is there a way to speed up table lookups where the id column is non-incrementing/non-sequential?

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a set of tables in MySQL where I do frequent lookups from a PHP program, with the two largest ones being ~160k entries. It takes a long time, on the order of 3 secs, for a not-too-horribly-complex query - e.g.,

```
select 
  if(
    p.gram_weight is null 
    or p.gram_weight = 0, 
    100, 
    cast(p.gram_weight as unsigned)
  ) as gms, 
  if(
    p.gram_weight is null 
    or p.gram_weight = 0, 
    '100 grams', 
    if(
      p.amount = 0, 
      p.portion_description, 
      concat_ws(
        ' ', 
        p.amount, 
        if(
          p.modifier = '', m.name, p.modifier
        )
      )
    )
  ) as unit 
from 
  food f 
  left join portions p on f.id = p.fdc_id 
  left join measures m on p.measure_unit_id = m.id 
where 
  f.description = $key 
order by 
  p.gram_weight;
```

The entries in the main table have IDs, but they're not necessarily sequential (although most of them are), and are actually meaningful, so they can't be changed.

What would be the most effective way for me to speed up these searches? Would I need to add an index column (to the main table? to all of them?), or can I use the ID column without having to make it sequential or reorganizing it in any way?

P.S. Running EXPLAIN on the query:

```
> explain select if(p.gram_weight is null or p.gram_weight = 0, 100, cast(p.gram_weight as unsigned)) as gms,          if(p.gram_weight is null or p.gram_weight = 0, '100 grams', if(p.amount = 0, p.portion_description,          concat_ws(' ', p.amount, if(p.modifier = '', m.name, p.modifier)))) as unit from food f left join portions p          on f.id=p.fdc_id left join measures m on p.measure_unit_id = m.id where f.description=quote('W and m, Roasted Coconut Chips') order by p.gram_weight\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: f
   partitions: NULL
         type: ALL
possible_keys: NULL
          key: NULL
      key_len: NULL
          ref: NULL
         rows: 158406
     filtered: 10.00
        Extra: Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
*************************** 2. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: p
   partitions: NULL
         type: ALL
possible_keys: NULL
          key: NULL
      key_len: NULL
          ref: NULL
         rows: 52560
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)
*************************** 3. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: m
   partitions: NULL
         type: eq_ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY
          key: PRIMARY
      key_len: 4
          ref: health.p.measure_unit_id
         rows: 1
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: NULL
3 rows in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

Looks like that produced a warning:

```
> show warnings;
+-------+------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Level | Code | Message




                                                                                                                   |
+-------+------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Note  | 1003 | /* select#1 */ select if(((`health`.`p`.`gram_weight` is null) or (`health`.`p`.`gram_weight` = 0)),100,cast(`health`.`p`.`gram_weight` as unsigned)) AS `gms`,if(((`health`.`p`.`gram_weight` is null) or (`health`.`p`.`gram_weight` = 0)),'100 grams',if((`health`.`p`.`amount` = 0),`health`.`p`.`portion_description`,concat_ws(' ',`health`.`p`.`amount`,if((`health`.`p`.`modifier` = ''),`health`.`m`.`name`,`health`.`p`.`modifier`)))) AS `unit` from `health`.`food` `f` left join `health`.`portions` `p` on((`health`.`p`.`fdc_id` = `health`.`f`.`id`)) left join `health`.`measures` `m` on((`health`.`m`.`id` = `health`.`p`.`measure_unit_id`)) where (`health`.`f`.`description` = <cache>(quote('W and m, Roasted Coconut Chips'))) order by `health`.`p`.`gram_weight` |
+-------+------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

The schemas:

```
*** ben@localhost health> describe food;
+-------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field       | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id          | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| description | text    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

*** ben@localhost health> describe measures;
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id    | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| name  | text    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

*** ben@localhost health> describe nutrients;
+--------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field  | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id     | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| fdc_id | int(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| amount | float   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+--------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
3 rows in set (0.01 sec)

*** ben@localhost health> describe portions;
+---------------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field               | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id                  | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| fdc_id              | int(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| amount              | float   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| measure_unit_id     | int(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| portion_description | text    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| modifier            | text    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| gram_weight         | float   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+---------------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Run this through `EXPLAIN`, and share that along with your current schema, with indexes.

Comment: Do you run this with the same keys often, while the data does not change that often? Then you could cache the result

Comment: Please remove the `php` tag from the question. It is miss leading, this has _nothing_ to do with php.

Comment: If you run this question on a regular base then you could consider building up an index for that. Something filled by a DB internal trigger that can be indexed efficiently.

Comment: @NicoHaase: you could say the data _never_ changes, but the lookups are usually all different (different types of food.)

Comment: @arkascha: I put PHP in because that's what queries the MySQL, and someone might offer a PHP-based solution. Do you still think it's irrelevant? Also: I'm not familiar with DB triggers, so I'd appreciate a code example.

Comment: @ceejayoz: Couldn't fit the EXPLAIN results into a comment, so added a P.S. to the original post. :)

Comment: You can see the `WHERE food.description` condition triggering a filesort because there's no index. This is the most likely culprit. Also, since this is a TEXT field there's not likely a meaningful way to index it. Are you literally keying this query on a _text_ description of a food item? Eg: "a tasty burger"?

Comment: @Sammitch Yep; I'm keying it on a text description. There's nothing else to key it on; that's all the input data I have. If you can suggest a better way, please do.

Comment: In the future, please use `SHOW CREATE TABLE` instead of `DESCRIBE`. The former includes more information that folks will just ask for anyway, like indexes , constraints, and table options.

Comment: Uhh... Bill Karwin is replying to you already, so all of my opinions are secondary. That said, indexing tables on arbitrary text strings is troublesome: 1. Because the match must be _exact_. 2. Because you can only index on the first X bytes of the string. 3. Depending on the encoding of the field that limit is quite limiting as there is a limit on how long the index data can be and 1 byte of UTF8 is stored as _four_ bytes. 4. Indexes need to be in memory for lookups, and a large table with max-length indices will require a lot of memory.

Comment: @Sammitch, UTF8 is a _variable-length_ encoding. I.e. each character in UTF8 takes between one and four bytes. If you make a string of UTF8 characters that happen to be in the ASCII range, they are all stored as one byte each. Only multi-byte characters need to be stored in 2, 3, or 4 bytes. But for purposes of index length, InnoDB must assume the worst case, that is, your string on some row could contain only emojis (or other 4-byte characters).

Comment: @BillKarwin I know. I suppose I could have better clarified that the codepoint width is only fixed to 4 bytes in the context of backend storage and indexing in mysql, but I was short on chars in that comment.

Comment: @Sammitch, In InnoDB, _"`CHAR(N)` columns occupy the maximum character byte length × `N` when using the `REDUNDANT` row format."_ See  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-row-format.html#innodb-compact-row-format-characteristics). That row format has not been the default for many years, so in virtually all cases, variable-length characters are stored in as few bytes as possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The query would benefit from the following two indexes:

```
ALTER TABLE food ADD INDEX (description(191));

ALTER TABLE portions ADD INDEX (fdc_id);
```

I had to specify an index prefix for `description` because a `text` column is too long to be indexed without using an index prefix.

The comments above about using triggers are misleading. No trigger is needed to keep an index maintained, MySQL does that automatically.

You might like my presentation [How to Design Indexes, Really](https://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/how-to-design-indexes-really), or the [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ELR7-RdU9XU).

I also wrote a chapter on indexing in my book, [SQL Antipatterns Volume 1](https://pragprog.com/titles/bksap1/sql-antipatterns-volume-1/).

Comment: Awesome! Thank you, Bill! I'm curious, though: why the '191' in the first statement? I just checked, and the longest description entry is 256 chars.

Comment: I chose it as a safe value, because depending on your character set and version of InnoDB, it might be the largest value supported. If you use a current version of InnoDB or a single-byte character set, you could make the prefix longer, but that's a separate discussion that is covered in the documentation. Even if some strings are 256 characters long, it's likely that they differ before the 192nd character!

Comment: Wow. Total one-stop shop solution here. :) Every query I test comes back with `0.00sec` for the run time. Thank you again!